# How to take screenshots in Selenium at different time intervals and save it at different place?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

By using below script, I am taking only one Screenshot every time, which it overrides on the same screenshot.

What should I do If I want to take different screenshots at some small time of interval?

```
public void screenShot() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    File scr=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    File dest= new File("filPath/1.png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(scr, dest);
    Thread.sleep(3000); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the current time to name your files, this example names the files after the current minutes and hours values (of course you may use seconds, milliseconds, days, whatever..) :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

String directory = "filPath";
String fileName = "snapshot_"+ hour + "_"+ minute +".png";

File dest = new File(directory, fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add timestamp to your file name, e.g.

```
public void screenShot() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
File scr=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    File dest= new File("filPath/screenshot_"+timestamp()+".png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(scr, dest);
    Thread.sleep(3000); 
}

public string timestamp() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
}
```